# Connecting Redux Store to Component to populate map with markers

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-maps

In short I'm trying to learn how to use redux. As the title suggests I'm trying to connect the redux store to the component so that it can populate the map with markers (that I've fetched on a server).

I know I have connected it when I load componentWillMount(). But by doing so it returns an array of objects, which is not what I exactly want.

I don't know if I'm saying this correctly, but how do I make it so that it returns a state / props that I can use in my ./Component to populate markers on a map?

[EDIT1: I've included changes as suggested Pritish]

Thanks in advance.

./Screen

```
class FindOnMapScreen extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userLocation: null,
      plots: []
    };
  }

  getUserLocationHandler = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      this.setState({
        userLocation: {
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0622,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }
      });
    }, err => console.log(err));
  };

componentDidMount() {
  this.props.onLoadPlacesToMap();
}

  render() {
    console.warn("props", this.props)
    return  (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FetchLocation onGetLocation={this.getUserLocationHandler} />
        <UsersMap 
          userLocation={this.state.userLocation}
          props={this.props.plots}
        />
      </View>
      )
    }
  };


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    plots: state.mapPlaces.plots
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
      onLoadPlacesToMap: () => dispatch(getPlacesOnMap())
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FindOnMapScreen);
```

./Component

```
const usersMap = props => {
let userLocationMarker = null;

if (props.userLocation) {
    userLocationMarker = <MapView.Marker coordinate={props.userLocation} />;
}

const plots = props.plots.map(plots => //.. tried to access here
    <MapView.Marker 
        coordinate={plots} 
        key={plots.id}
    />
);

return (
    <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
        <MapView 
            initialRegion={{
                latitude: 37.78825,
                longitude: -122.4324,
                latitudeDelta: 0.0622,
                longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            }}
            region={props.userLocation}
            style={styles.map}
        >
            {userLocationMarker}
        </MapView>
    </View>
  );
};
```

./Store/Actions

```
export const getPlacesOnMap = () => {
return dispatch => {
    dispatch(authGetToken())
        .then(token => {
            return fetch("myAppURL/file.json?auth=" + token);
        })
        .catch(() => {
            alert("No valid token found!");
        })
        .then(res => {
            if (res.ok) {
                return res.json();
            } else {
                throw(new Error());
            }
        })
        .then(parsedRes => {
            const plots = [];
            for (let key in parsedRes) {
                plots.push({
                    latitude: parsedRes[key].location.latitude,
                    longitude: parsedRes[key].location.longitude,
                    id: key
                  });
                } console.log(plots)
                dispatch(mapPlaces(plots));
              })
        .catch(err => {
            alert("Oops! Something went wrong, sorry! :/");
            console.log(err);
        });
    };
};

export const mapPlaces = plots => {
    return {
        type: MAP_PLACES,
        plots: plots
    };
};
```

./Store/Reducer

```
const initialState ={
    plots: []
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case MAP_PLACES:
        return {
            ...state,
            places: action.plots
        };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

./ConfigureStore

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    mapPlaces: mapPlacesReducer
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your **Component** is a *stateless* one, you can pass the **plot** `props` to it directly from `this.props` which is bound to the *state of the store* using `mapStateToProps`.

```
componentDidMount {
  this.props.onLoadPlacesToMap() // ... Call your prop bound dispatcher func here
}

<UsersMap 
   userLocation={this.state.userLocation} 
   plots={this.props.plots}
/>
```

and in your **Component** , you can access them by `props.plots`

In your reducer , you need to either change `places` to `plots` or map and map them similarly in your parent class.

```
case MAP_PLACES:
   return {
     ...state,
     plots: action.plots
 };
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @pritsh. Sadly, I think you may be right about combining my reducers correctly. Because when I included your suggestions, nothing happens to the map aha. I'm gonna take a look at it and figure out why. But in the meantime, I've updated my code above to include the combineReducers.

Comment: You need to replace `places` to `plots` since in your `mapStateToProps` you're asking for `plots: state.mapPlaces.plots`

Comment: Hahaha how did I miss that. Thanks @Pritish!